# Trying to calculate the number of items in a table that have a relationship with another

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm getting data from the posts table and there is a likes table that is related to this. I want to know how many likes each post has. I followed an example, but this way it gives an error.
I will leave the error after the code

```
$data = Post::query();
$data = $data->leftJoin('likes', 'posts.id', '=', 'likes.post_id');
$data = $data->selectRaw('posts.id, posts.status, COUNT(likes.id) AS curtidas')->groupBy('posts.id');
$data = $data->get();
```

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1055
```

Comment: Are you intentionally grouping by just one column when you are selecting two columns? Does it error if you remove `posts.status` from your selectRaw statement or add it to your groupBy clause?

Comment: It worked, why? I need to select other columns, how do I do it?

Comment: When aggregating, you typically need to group by the columns you are selecting. `select col1, col2, col3, count(col4) from... where... group by col1, col2, col3`

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, you can modify your query like this:

```
$data = Post::query();
$data = $data->leftJoin('likes', 'posts.id', '=', 'likes.post_id');
$data = $data->selectRaw('posts.id, posts.status, COUNT(likes.id) AS curtidas');
$data = $data->groupBy('posts.id', 'posts.status'); 
$data = $data->get();
```

But you can achieve the same result with a simpler query by using Laravel's Eloquent relationships and the withCount method.

```
//inside you Post modle
public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Like::class);
}
```

Then, you can use the withCount method to retrieve the total likes for each post like this:

```
$data = Post::withCount('likes')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Laravel's Eloquent to achieve this; assuming there is a `likes` relationship between the `Post` and `Like` model, you could do this:

```
$posts = Post::query()
    ->withCount('likes')
    ->get();
```

Note that Laravel loads the number of likes in `likes_count` property on each post.